# Spring Roo : mvn clean install

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am using spring roo to build web application. In STS IDE, Some time When I do the clean and build war file using apache maven tool that is show error that domain entities and methods not found when domain entity and methods exist. After some time when refresh the project that problem is resolve itself. I do not understand that what is actual problem for this.

How can I ignore this problem.
Suggestion will helpful.

Ajay

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an IDE problem, so try to change it to eclipse for example and see if it works.

Comment: In Eclipse IDE, That have same problem.

Comment: Hi Jaochm, Thanks for your response. I resolved this problem. Problem is that I was changing my system date and making build using maven. That time is caching system date and showing error. When I updated current system date and again make build then It's working. So, Problem is date of system.